# jQuery - How to make two fields required based on the value of the third field

Tags: jquery, html

I have to create a required field validating based on another non-empty field.
Currently I have three fields - Country code , state code and residence.

AAA) If the residence number is **not empty** and the state code and country code is empty, it should show an error. This currently works for one field, but not the other field. How can I get working for the other field as well.

Code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("Hello1");
            $("#step1").validate({   
                rules: {
                    countrycode1: {
                        required: {
                            depends: function(element){
                                return $("#residence").val()!="";
                                console.log("Hello5");
                            }
                        }
                    }           
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="step1" action="#" method="post">
        <label>Country Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="countrycode1" name="countrycode1" value="91"/></br>

        <label>Std Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="stdcode" id="stdcode" value="80"/></br>

        <label>Residence</label>
        <input type="text" name="residence" id="residence" /></br>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="next step" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/8/)

Comment: @Rory I have got the first input field working. But, I don't know how to get it working for two fields at the same time

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/10/

Just add another rule for the second field.

```
     $("#step1").validate({

         rules: {
             countrycode1: {
                 required: {
                     depends: function(element){
                         return $("#residence").val()!=""
                     }
                 }
             },
             stdcode: {
                 required: {
                     depends: function(element){
                         return $("#residence").val()!=""
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly,

Simply specify both fields as dependant as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Hello1");
        $("#step1").validate({   
            rules: {
                countrycode1: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element){
                            return $("#residence").val()!="";
                        }
                    }
                } ,
                stdcode: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element){
                            return $("#residence").val()!="";
                        }
                    }
                }   

            }
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/yFXXL/)

*If it is not the expected behaviour comment below or try making the question bit more clear..*